# Sign error in Chriss-Ginzburg?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, geometric-representation-theory

On page 118, Theorem 2.7.26 (iii) in Chriss-Ginzburg "Representation Theory and Complex Geometry" there is a formula for the convolution of the classes of conormal bundles of $Y_{12}\subset X_1\times X_2$ and $Y_{23}\subset X_2\times X_3$ inside the corresponding cotangent bundles. Suppose $p_{12}^{-1}(Y_{12}) \cap p_{23}^{-1}(Y_{23}) \to Y_{13}$ is a fibration with fiber smooth compact $F$. Then it is claimed that $[Z_{12}]*[Z_{23}] = \chi(F) [Z_{13}]$, where $Z_{ij}$ denotes the conormal to $Y_{ij}$ in $T^* X_{ij}$. But I cannot reproduce exactly this. It seems there is a sign $(-1)^{\dim_{\mathbb{C}} F}$ missing.

Also there is Remark 2.7.27 (1), right after the Theorem, saying that the self-intersection of the zero section in $T^* F$ is the Euler characteristic, but that is not correct, the correct statement is about the tangent bundle. The Euler class of the cotangent bundle differs by a factor $(-1)^{\dim_{\mathbb{C}} F}$.

Assuming I am right about this, afterwards when this is used in Section 4, one has to introduce sign corrections in the construction of $sl_n$-representations, otherwise it doesn't work. I didn't check if this error propagates further in the book.

Am I right? Had anyone else noticed?

Comment: I have noticed the issue with sign in the the self-intersection before and was confused by it. I also struggled with signs in the book at times, particularly in the sections establishing the K-theory realization of the affine Hecke algebra. At the same time, I find the book extremely useful and inspiring!

Comment: It is a mistake. A simple counterexample is $X_1 = X_3 = pt$, $X_2 = \mathbb P^1$, $Y_{12}= Y_{23} = \mathbb P^1$. Then $[Z_{12}]*[Z_{23}]$ is the self-intersection number of $\mathbb P^1$ in $T^*\mathbb P^1$, which is $-2$, negative of the Euler number od $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: I also noticed (and was confused by) this mistake in the past.  And, Hiraku's counterexample is perfect.  I'd like to draw attention to a possible deeper significance of this missing sign.  We have constructions of convolution algebras in homology and in constructible functions and it would be useful to compare them.  For example to relate Lusztig's semicanonical basis with Nakajima's basis coming from the homology of quiver varieties (another example arises in my paper with Fontaine and Kuperberg).

Comment: If we work with constructible functions, this sign wouldn't occur.  So it would seem that this sign prevents us from defining the natural map between convolution algebras in homology and in constructible functions.  Did anyone think about this before and see a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: I don't have the book on my at the moment, but from an email I once wrote to Alistair Savage, I think that this mistake in the proof occurs with the indentification $T/T_1 + T_2 = \pi^* T_{Y/Y_{13}}$.  It should actually be the dual on the right hand side.

Comment: @Joel I was trying to motivate some construction in the book by first computing the analogous thing over finite fields, which should be equivalent to your constructible functions suggestion. But there the problem was that I had to set $q=1$ so that the relations hold. Then I was hoping that the Borel-Moore homology would precisely be the right analogy to setting $q=1$, and it does seem to work, but up to this strange sign correction

Comment: @Joel yes, the $T/T_1+T_2=$ claim in the proof is where the mistake happens. All these $T$-s are in the cotangent direction.